# How can I convert the following code from class to const

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, react-spring

[image]

I have tried to convert the  bets part into const , I am not sure how to do it. The roll and the count i ve managed to get it

Comment: Do you want to be functional component out of it?

Answer (score 2):

```
import { useState } from "react;
const Roulette = () => {
  const [roll, setRoll] = useState(true);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(false);
  const [bets, setBets] = useState({
    red: [],
    green: [],
    black: []
  });

  return (
    ...code
  );
};
```

Assumed you just wanted a functional component

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this  :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Wheel from './wheel'
import Countdown from './countdown'
import Bets from './bets'
import Input from './input'

function Roulette() {
  const [roll , setRoll] = useState(true)
  const [count , setCount] = useState(false)
  const [bets , setBets] = useState({red : [], green :[], black: []})

  return (
    <div>
       {/* Your code goes here  */}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Roulette ;
```